# DropDownList Children Binding

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik

I have an issue with a dropdownlist and I can't figure it out how to solve it.

There are two different way to get into my view: Add New and Edit.

1) Add New: In this situation my dropdownlist is related to another one, and everything works great.
the dropdownlist is locked and empty until I select something in the other one.

2) Edit: In this situation my dropdownlist is already binded using stored data. Of course if I change the selected item in the "parent" one I want to change data to the children too.

The problem appears in the 2 case: When I select something else out of the stored data in the related dropdownlist.
It binds the correct data, but it gives an empty item as first, and not the first of the data.

How can I solve it?

```
                            <%=Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.GNR_FK)
                                .Name("GNR_FK")                                                                 .BindTo((IEnumerable<Models.Widget.Combo>)ViewData["Customer"])
                                .DataTextField("descriptionText")
                                .DataValueField("valueID")
                                .Value(Model.GNR_FK.ToString())
                                .Events(e =>
                                        {
                                            e.Select("onSelect");
                                        })                                            
                            %>

                            <%=Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.CNT_FK)                                    .BindTo((IEnumerable<Models.Widget.Combo>)ViewData["Sender"])
                                .Name("CNT_FK")
                                .DataTextField("descriptionText")
                                .DataValueField("valueID")
                                %>
```

Condition:

```
        if (Model.PK == 0)
        {
            loadValues(current);
        }
        else
        {
            loadEditValues(current);
        }


    public JsonResult loadValues(Models.Model current, int PK = 0)
    {

            IDataReader sender = Model.getSender(PK);
            Models.Widget.Combo SenderNA = new Models.Widget.Combo();
            List<Models.Widget.Combo> receiveSender = new List<Models.Widget.Combo>();

            SenderNA.valueID = 0;
            SenderNA.descriptionText = "NA";
            receiveSender.Add(SenderNA);

            while (sender.Read())
            {
                Models.Widget.Combo newItem = new Models.Widget.Combo();

                newItem.valueID = int.Parse(sender["PK"].ToString());
                newItem.descriptionText = sender["SURNAME"].ToString();

                receiveSender.Add(newListItem);
            }

            return Json(receiveSender, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }


    private void loadEditValues(Models.Model current)
    {

            int selected = current.GNR_FK;

            IDataReader sender = current.getSender(selectedCustomer);

            Models.Widget.Combo SenderNA = new Models.Widget.Combo();
            List<Models.Widget.Combo> receiveSender = new List<Models.Widget.Combo>();

            SenderNA.valueID = 0;
            SenderNA.descriptionText = "NA";
            receiveSender.Add(SenderNA);

            while (sender.Read())
            {
                Models.Widget.Combo newItem = new Models.Widget.Combo();

                newItem.valueID = int.Parse(sender["PK"].ToString());
                newItem.descriptionText = sender["SURNAME"].ToString();

                receiveSender.Add(newListItem);            


                ViewData["List"] = receiveSender;
            }         

    }
```

Script:

```
   function onSelect(e) {
        var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item);
        var PK = dataItem.valueID;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Project/loadValues',
            data: "{'PK':'" + PK + "'}",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

            success: function (result) {     
                $("#CNT_FK").data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource.data(result);

            },
            error: function (err, result) {
                alert("Error" + err.responseText);
            }

        });
    }
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved!

It was missing the select method to automatically select the first item after changing data!

```
success: function (result) {
    var dropdown = $("#CNT_FK").data("kendoDropDownList");
    dropdown.dataSource.data(result);
    dropdown.select(0);
},
```